# Height of UITableView changed after scroll the view

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I use `UIScrollView` with two tableviews. One of them is dynamic height changed because I insert cells in runtime and the second table is fixed height.
When the application runs and adds cells to the first table everthing is normal and it changed the height of the table and the height of the contentsize of scrollview.

The problem is: when I scroll and `scrollViewDidScroll` was called the height of first tableview returns to its initial height and cells were added get nil, the second table view didn't create a problem because its height is fixed.

Note: I used constraints and removed them (the problem remained).

What's the wrong? I use iOS 8 and xCode 6.1.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When adding a new cell are you adding the object in you array (used in your data source methods) as well ??

Comment: yes and checked the array after the problem , give me the number of cells were added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by add constraints on **UITableView**

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButton
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                              toItem:nil
                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                          multiplier:1.0
                                            constant:30.0]];
```

because I use auto-layout 
I hope this answer help anyone

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's difficult to help you, but try to check the function in the tableview :
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I checked and return the  initial height :(